# Detecting if a polynomial is a Pfaffian

Tags: matrices, polynomials, determinants, pfaffian

Given an explicit polynomial, is there any kind of trick/algorithm to check whether it is a pfaffian of a matrix with linear entries?

The pfaffian can be defined as $\sqrt{{\rm det}(A) } $ when $A$ is skew symmetric, or explicitly $${\rm pf}(A) = \frac{1}{2^n n!}\sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_{2n}}{\rm sgn} (\sigma)\prod\limits_{j=1}^n a_{\sigma (2j -1 ),\sigma(2j)}.$$

Comment: What is a Pfaffian polynomial? 

Comment: Please try to improve the question! As it stands, it might (and probably should) get closed for lack of clarity, motivation etc.

Comment: As motivation for related questions, Mumford gives, in his first paper on Prym varieties, an explicit Pfaffian of linear forms, which defines the tangent cone to the theta divisor of a Prym variety precisely when that Pfaffian is not identically zero.  When this occurs is more complicated however and was only settled some 25 years later.

Comment: I am sorry for the sloppyness of the question. I assumed, without stating, that the matrix had linear entries. Now I've edited it.

Comment: The Pfaffian of a skew symmetric matrix is a polynomial in the entries of the matrix, whose square is the determinant of the matrix, as given in your explicit formula. But the Pfaffian of a real matrix can be positive or negative, so the Pfaffian is not the square root, but only one of the two square roots, of the determinant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Bruce Westubury noticed, the answer to this question is trivial as it is stated.

Surprisingly enough, however, the situation becomes very interesting when one considers representations of *homogeneous* polynomials as pfaffians of matrices with *linear* entries.

More precisely, let us consider the following version of the question:

> **Question.** Let $F \in k[x_0, \ldots, x_n   ]$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$.
>   Does there exist a symmetric (resp. antisymmetric) matrix $M$, whose entries are linear forms, such that 
>   $$\det(M)=F \quad (\textrm{resp}. \  \textrm{Pf}(M)=F)?$$

This problem is studied in detail in Beauville's paper [[Symmetric determinantal hypersurfaces](http://www-math.unice.fr/publis/beauvill_det.ps), Michigan Mathematical Journal 48 (2000)], where the existence of a symmetric or pfaffian representation is related to the existence of certain vector bundles on the projective variety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ defined by $F=0$.

Among other things, Beauville proves the following results (when $k= \mathbb{C}$):

$\bullet$ A general polynomial of degree $d$ admits a determinantal representation if and only if $$n=2 \quad \textrm{or}$$ $$n=3 \quad \textrm{and} \quad d\leq 3.$$

$\bullet$ A general polynomial of degree $d$ admits a pfaffian  representation if and only if $$n=2,$$ $$n=3 \quad \textrm{and} \quad d \leq 15 \quad \textrm{or}$$   $$n=4 \quad \textrm{and} \quad d \leq 5.$$

Answer (score 13):

The Pfaffian of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\\\ -A & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is $\det A$. Since any polynomial is a determinant this means any polynomial is a Pfaffian.

Answer (score 5):

Now that the question makes sense, let me mention the following result (you can find it in Eisenbud, Exercise 20.17) which hinted at what Francesco wrote.

Let $R = k[[x,y,z]]$ and $f\in m=(x,y,z)$. Then $f$ is a determinant of a matrix (of size at least $2$) with entries in $m$ iff $R/(f)$ is *not* a UFD!